# How to load local html files to make a host?

Tags: wordpress, web

I want to build a personal homepage comprised of several static pages like 
about me, contact, hobby, etc.

I find wordpress too complicated for this purpose.

My preferred way is as follows:

1. download to my local disk the source code of someone's homepage, such as [this](http://academic.patrick.wagstrom.net/)
2. Modify the contents so that his name is changed to my name, his affiliation is changed to mine, etc.
3. Upload this local htmls to the web.

I don't know how to do step 3. I have currently bought a name domain from namecheap and it is hosted on hostblue. Wordpress is installed on the host but I find it time-wasting to get used to its fancy user interfaces -- reasons that I would prefer an easy way from the top of my head.

Can anyone tell me how to do step 3? Thanks

Comment: You are looking for an FTP client like FileZilla: https://filezilla-project.org/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Follow these steps:
1) Download fresh copy of wordpress.
2) Copy any theme and rename according to your wish. Open it and go to style.css
   remove all css code from "style.css" file. Now copy your static site's css 
   and paste in "style.css" file. But at the top of css write this code:
   /*
   Theme Name: Your Theme Name
   */
 3) Open Filezilla and fill the server details ( eg. hostname, password, username ).
 4) If you are connected, open public_html folder and upload wordpress folder here.
 5) It will take time to upload. Wait...
 6) If successfully uploaded to the host, open your browser and type your sitename.
 7) You will be asked to fill some information ( eg. database name, password etc ).
 8) If you filled all information correctly then good.
    Cheers!!! Your site is ready on Wordpress.
    Let me know what happened?
```